# how do I get the text from the checkbox?

Tags: python, pyqt, click, qcheckbox

I have built a group checkbox by:

```
self.group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
```

How can I get the checkbox text which is/are clicked ?

```
self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.btnCliked)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`buttonClicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) signal sends the button that was clicked, so all you need is:

```
    def btnClicked(self, button):
        print(button.text())
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the button/radios/checks exclusively (meaning just one can be selected at a time)?
Depending on what you want to do you can either use the argument of the "clicked"-signal like:

```
self.group.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

def btnClicked(self, button):
    self.text = button.text()
```

or you can also use each on_button_clicked function, which is pretty much the same (you dont need to connect the signal, its done automatically):

```
...
@QtCore.pyqtSignature('')
def on_mybutton1_clicked(self, button):
    self.text = button.text()

@QtCore.pyqtSignature('')
def on_mybutton2_clicked(self, button):
    self.text = button.text()
...
```

("mybutton1" in "on_mybutton1_clicked" is the name of each button)

or if you want to get the state at a action later on, like at a button press of another button, you can do it like:

```
def on_anyaction(self):
    button = self.group.selected()
    self.text = button.text()
```

I hope this helps an gives you some input...